# Draw NavigationView header below status bar with NavigationView behind status bar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, navigationview, android-navigationview

I have been trying to draw the NavigationView header below the status bar, but it stays behind the status bar.

I have already set the property `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` for both my DrawerLayout as well as my NavigationView, but to no avail.

Here's the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_dashboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="scrollable">

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image: This is how it looks currently]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @RayKoopa add this line android:fitsSystemWindows="false" to drawer layout

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue, on your NavigationView set fitsSystemWindows to false, leave rest as is.
From what I understood from API >= 21 NavigationView goes behind status bar

Comment: doing that makes the NavigationView BELOW the status bar. i dont want this behaviour. i want the NavigationView to draw behind the status bar but the header should be below the status bar.

Answer (score 8):

Did you try to `setFitsSystemWindows` to `false` on the header View?

If you did and it did not work you can set a padding top to your View manually by observing the `onApplyWindowInsetsListener` on the header View or on the `NavigationView`:

```
 ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(headerView) { view, insets ->
      view.setPadding(0, insets.systemWindowInsetTop, 0, 0)
      insets
 }
```

Comment: This worked for me.  I needed to keep setFitsSystemWindows as true for other reasons.  Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, worked like charm. Added the setFitsSystemWindows setted to false in the navigation view that contains the header, and another setFitsSystemWindows setted to true in the drawer layout.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the root of your header layout? This worked for me.

Comment: You can see yourself he has that in his code, which causes his navigation view to be _under_ the statusbar, but not _below_ it.

Comment: @RayKoopa No. You can only see the reference to the header layout app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header" not the content of the header itself. Adding android:fitsSystemWindows="true" on the root view of the header also worked great for me.

Comment: Then there seems to be different behavior on my and your device, it had to be `false` for me.